# Displaying a custom control when clicking UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

In `iOS`, when a `UITextField` is clicked, a system default number pad will pop up. I've made my own control. I want to bring up my own control when clicking the `UITextField`, just like the system default number pad. Can I do that in programming? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide keyboard by `[self.view endEditing:YES];` and show your own control.

Try above line of code below `UITextField` delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;        // return NO to disallow editing.
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;           // became first responder
```

Comment: Then how to add my own control when clicking?

Comment: @GoddessGuard - You can do it by animation

Comment: You may do it by presenting a view controller with your control on it.

Comment: @GoddessGuard - First hide keyboard in above delegate methods then in the same method then add launch code in your control

Answer (score 2):

There is a property for this purpose. Simply assign it with your custom control's view like this:

```
[yourTextField setInputView:yourCustomControlsView];
```

Answer (score 0):

With a custom view and custom buttons. The keyboard itself is something very easy to do, you just need to place some buttons on a view and then show that view. Your real problem will be connecting the button actions to the text field.

You would have to check for the first responder and then add to its text the value corresponding to your custom keyboard. It will be an even more difficult problem to actually "type" those weird characters from the keyboard in the text field. I am not familiar with them, are those real ASCII characters?

Anyway, you're in for quite some work. It's not something very difficult to code, requiring some complicate algorithms, but the implementation will be tricky and complex, so be careful

Comment: I just want to display a customized number pad. So how to bring it up when clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Make sure you assign the delegates to the `UITextField`.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    CustomNumberPadViewController *customNumberPadViewController = [[CustomNumberPadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomNumberPadView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:CustomNumberPadViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```